# Divide two variables in Twig/PHP

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to do something that I think should be very simple with Twig however I am receiving an error.

I simply want to divide two variables ...

```
{% set thist1 = attribute(mD, WMData[b] ~ 'sales') %} 
{% set thist2 = attribute(mD, WMData[b] ~ 'trans') %} 
{% set thisDone = thist1 / thist2 %}
```

If I echo out thist1 and thist2 they are both numbers ... for example {{ thist1 }} {{ thist2 }} = 4805.05 43

However I am receiving the below error ...

```
Warning: Division by zero in ~/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 326
```

Comment: Please verify your input as this [code](https://twigfiddle.com/g5uig2) works as is.

Comment: I am guessing that you're looping over a value that is empty. Adding a condition to validate the data would resolve the `division by zero error`. `{% set thisDone = (thist1 and thist2 ? thist1 / thist2 : 0) %}`

Comment: Twig as a templating engine should only need to display the [business logic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html) (calculations) defined by your Models. You should pass your `mD` argument(s) to a model that performs the desired business logic. Then pass twig the model/collection of models and call the method(s) for the desired data `{{ mDModel.done }}` This way if you need to display the same calculation elsewhere (in the future), you will not need to maintain duplicates.

Comment: Here is a twigfiddle to show you like @DarkBee mentioned that your code should work: https://twigfiddle.com/nmaxu1